# How can I use load view engine in router file?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to return html file in my routes/profile.js file. I was trying to use pug and stuff, however, I could not find any example that stating app.set and app.engine in other files than the index.js?

this is my index.js

```
const port = config.port;
const app = express();

// Load View Engine

app.options('*', cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Routes
app.use('/gateway/userprofile', userProfile)

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server up and running on port ${port}`));
```

and it is my 'route/userProfile.js' file's controller

```
  static async sendVerificationEmail(req, res) {
    const userEmail = req.body.userEmail;
    console.log(userEmail);
    try {
      await axios.post(`http://123.42352.34234`, {
        type: 'UserProfileEmailVerification',
        userEmail,
      });
      console.log(
        colors.yellow.underline.bold(
          'Gateway -> BeUserProfile Sending Verification Email Succeed'
        )
      );
      res.sendStatus({ emailSent: 'successful' });
    } catch (err) {
      res.sendStatus(400);
    }
  }
```

I am trying to return the HTML file here. Is there any way that I can use app.egine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your index.js add:

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

Where 'views' on this case is the folder with .pug files and you can use .pug on any file

Check a full code sample here:
https://github.com/jonasschmedtmann/complete-node-bootcamp/blob/master/4-natours/after-section-14/app.js

Comment: Yes, but then how can I do app.set in 'route/userProfile.js'? Do I have to import express and app?

Comment: Import express yes, if the index.js is the start file of the proyect you don't need to import app, is already setted